Meaning of hyphen in define and end at a Go template/Helm template
At the Go/Helm template, we can use - for removing leading and trailing spaces.
Go document said

For this trimming, the definition of white space characters is the same as in Go: space, horizontal tab, carriage return, and newline.


{{- /* a comment with white space trimmed from preceding and following text */ -}}
A comment; discarded. May contain newlines.
Comments do not nest and must start and end at the
delimiters, as shown here.

But I can't understand what happen when we use - in the front and the back of define and end. Because I think define and end are like kinds of a function, we don't need to use -.
{{- define "test" -}}
Test helper function
{{- end -}}

For checking it, I tested all possible cases at Helm playground. https://helm-playground.com/
But I can't interpret it. Would you help me a little?
Test cases I did
Case 0 : Not use the dash anywhere

template.yaml

---
{{ define "test" }}
Test helper function
{{ end }}


Test template start
{{include "test" .}}
Test template end


output

---



Test template start

Test helper function

Test template end

Case 1 : Use the dash in the front of define

template.yaml

---
{{- define "test" }}
Test helper function
{{ end }}


Test template start
{{include "test" .}}
Test template end


output

---


Test template start

Test helper function

Test template end

Case 2 : Use the dash in the back of define

template.yaml

---
{{ define "test" -}}
Test helper function
{{ end }}


Test template start
{{include "test" .}}
Test template end


output

---



Test template start
Test helper function

Test template end

Case 3 : Use the dash in the front of end

template.yaml

---
{{ define "test" }}
Test helper function
{{- end }}


Test template start
{{include "test" .}}
Test template end


output

---



Test template start

Test helper function
Test template end

Case 4 : Use the dash in the back of end

template.yaml

---
{{ define "test" }}
Test helper function
{{ end -}}


Test template start
{{include "test" .}}
Test template end


output

---
Test template start

Test helper function

Test template end


See https://go.dev/play/p/dHGU06mw3jr for a demonstration of - with define and end.  The whitespace is removed as documented.

The whitespace are removed at the place the define is done, not during use of the template. This are the more or less blank lines at the beginning of your output.

Related: What is the difference between {{- range .Values.xxx }} and {{ range .Values.xxx }} in Helm; How to know, when I have to use {{- instead of {{ when producing yaml?

You also might try rendering '{{ include "test" . }}' with your various combinations of -.  This will make it more visible when that template's response begins and ends with newlines.

I feel shamed about my question. I missed the point that the spaces are removed on the place where it is declared. If you think this question is not proper, I will remove or close the question. Feel free to say to me.

Or, if you add an answer this question, I will accept it. Thank you for helping me! :bow:
